How to prevent row re-ordering on cell data update using ag-grid
I have an ag-grid table where the data is updated using async transactions. I need to have two modes (toggled by button click): one where rows are automatically re-ordered when data is updated as usual, and another where after sorting by column asc/desc that order is then preserved through updates - effectively freezing rows in place.
Is this possible to achieve without some sort of hacky workaround?
I've read through the ag-grid docs, and not found options for maintaining row order without just disabling sorting
